# Wireless mouse with a Bluetooth receiver

Tags: bluetooth, wireless-mouse

The item is a wireless mouse with a Bluetooth receiver. Would this work with a laptop without the receiver if the laptop has Bluetooth?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here - what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Voting to close - essentially this appears to be a shopping question or hardware rec (which is off topic), it's unclear as you've not stated what mouse, recevier, computer etc... However, you can edit your question to provide the detail which we need in order to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a true Bluetooth mouse, of course you connect it to a Bluetooth enabled PC with the proper drivers installed for the Bluetooth services. This is a basic function of Bluetooth and I have done it on Windows and Linux PC's.

Be aware however, all cordless mice (and keyboards) are NOT Bluetooth, such as Logitech which uses it's own proprietary "Unifying" receiver. Most cordless mice are proprietary to their dongles, unless you specifically purchase one that is Bluetooth compatible.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is advertised as a Wireless Mouse with a Blue Tooth receiver. I thought that was odd as if the receiver is Blue Tooth then the mouse must be as well. I was just not sure why a receiver was necessary at all - but I guess desktops would need it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is a WAG as your question is not very clear. But here's my guess.

You have a computer. It has bluetooth.

You have a mouse. It has a receiver that goes into your computer for wireless usage. It also has bluetooth.

If I am reading your question right, you want to know if you can use the mouse in bluetooth mode, without having the wireless receiver plugged in.

Whether the mouse works with your computer, depends on the computer though. There are different versions of bluetooth, and different operating systems, which supports different functionalities. If you can give the computer, operating system and mouse model and make, then we should be able to determine if they are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Cheap from China - model unknown. I used to buy Logitech or Microsoft but have about 20 wireless mice I can't use as I always lose the receiver somewhere along the way. Wondered if a blue tooth one would be better as may be able to use it without the receiver -  HP Elitebook and Windows 8.1